# Which of the meaning of ‘ghost’ is meant in the phrase ‘ghost authorship’?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Ghost authorship is essentially the opposite of honorary authorship,
> entailing a significant contribution to a manuscript without
> acknowledgment of that contribution. The most well-known scenario
> involves a professional medical writer or an industry researcher who
> drafts an article on behalf of a pharmaceutical company but is not
> credited for this work. ([Source](https://www.aje.com/arc/ghost-authorship/))

I can understand the meaning of the phrase ‘ghost authorship’. It is clearly defined above. But my question is which of the meanings of ‘ghost’ is here taken advantage of to create this phrase. There is nothing close to ‘unmentioned’ among the meanings of ‘ghost’. And ‘dead’ doesn’t work because the ghost author can be alive.

There is also the phrase ghostwrite meaning:

> to write a book, article, etc. for another person to publish under
> their own name. ([Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ghost))

Again, my question is about what meaning of ‘ghost’ is employed here to make that phrase.

In [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ghost) too, one of the meanings of ‘ghost’ is ‘one who ghostwrites ’. None of its other meanings I can link to the meaning of ‘ghost authorship’.

Answer (score 6):

I think the metaphor behind *ghostwriter* and related words is of a ghost as an entity that is unseen or at least difficult to see (despite potentially causing more perceptible effects). Likewise, the product of a ghostwriter is perceptible but the author is not made known.

Relevant definition of *ghost*:

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ghost):

> 2 : a disembodied soul
> especially : the soul of a dead person believed to be **an inhabitant of the unseen world** or to appear to the living in bodily likeness

Comment: Right. It's the invisibility of ghosts in Western mythology that leads to the prefix meaning 'something there but you can't see it'. By convention, ghost writers are not credited, just paid. Co-authors are usually considered to have done most of the writing when paired with a famous author, but they're not considered "ghost".